# How to listen to smart contract emitted events using C#

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, nethereum, c#

I have to add/update some data in a database when specific **events are emitted by a solidity smart contract**. When using `web3.js` there is a simple method called `watch()`, but I didn't find anything like that in the [Nethereum](https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/nethereum-events-gettingstarted/) C# library.

There is an example in web3.js:

```js
var instructorEvent = Coursetro.Instructor();
instructorEvent.watch(function(error, result){
     ...
});
```

Another way to do it using web3.js:

```js
myContract.events.MyEvent({})
    .on('data', async function(event){
        console.log(event.returnValues);
        // Do something here
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
```

It hasn't to be a solution with Nethereum but has to work on C#. In case I don't discover an answer to C#, I will try it using a Node.JS API.

Comment: json-rpc - https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API - eth_getLogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streaming websocket client. It is present in the docs - https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/introduction/ws/